# Closed subspace and weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $V$ be a Banach space and $W$ be a closed subspace of $V$. Show that the weak topology on $W$ is the topology induced on $W$ by the weak topology on $V$.

I read in some places that this follows direct from the Hahn-Banach Theorem, but I'm not sure how to argue. If someone already solved this kind of problem, please give me any idea. Appreciate!

My first idea is double inclusion, i. e., show that $$\sigma(W,W^\star)=\sigma(V,V^\star)|_W.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_{\delta})\subseteq M$ and $x\in M$, we are to show that $x_{\delta}\rightarrow x$ weakly in $M$ if and only if $x_{\delta}\rightarrow x$ weakly in $X$.

We need to pair with $m^{\ast}\in M^{\ast}$ and $x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}$. But Hahn-Banach gives every $m^{\ast}$ to an extension $x_{m}^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}$ and each $x^{\ast}$ with the restriction $x^{\ast}|_{M}$ to $M$ is obviously an element of $M^{\ast}$.

Comment: So, is enough prove that “weak convergence of a sequence in $W$ if, and only if, weak convergence in $V$” to conclude that the topologies are the same?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Because from this you can infer the continuity of the identity map $i:(W,\tau_{w^{\ast}-W})\rightarrow(X,\tau_{w^{\ast}-X})$ and vice versa.